# ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo

I'm migrating some modules from v7 to v10

Right now I have these methods which inherit `res.partner`

```
@api.depends('company_id')
def _get_country_code(self):
    """
    Return the country code of the user company. If not exists, return XX.
    """
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    for partner in self:
        user_company = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.company_id)
        #NOTE: replace code name with your real field name where you want to see value 
        partner.code = user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id \
            and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'

@api.multi
def default_get(self, field_list):
    """ Load the country code of the user company to form to be created.
    """
    # NOTE: use field_list argument instead of fields for fix the pylint
    # error W0621 Redefining name 'fields' from outer scope
    context = {}
    res = super(ResPartner, self).default_get(field_list)
    res.update({'uid_country': self._get_country_code })
    return res

@api.multi
def _get_uid_country(self):
    """ Return a dictionary of key ids as invoices, and value the country code
    of the user company.
    """
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code())
    return res
```

I have this error every time I try to create or read a partner:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 2995, in read
values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], record, use_name_get)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 5171, in __getitem__
return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 860, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 969, in determine_value
self.compute_value(recs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 924, in compute_value
self._compute_value(records)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 918, in _compute_value
self.compute(records)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/partner.py", line 73, in _get_uid_country
res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code())
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/partner.py", line 51, in _get_country_code
user_company = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.company_id)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 854, in __get__
record.ensure_one()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4783, in ensure_one
raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 33, 8, 18, 22, 23)
```

I'm struggling with this, also, do You think it will be easier to migrate from v8 instead of v7, to v10?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expected Singleton:**

Class methods required **single invoking object (Single Browsable Record)** to invoke the method and suppose it will call by **multiple invoking objects (Browsable Recordsets)** then method is not able to identify for which object it should process, therefore it will raise an error **Expected Singleton**.

New API decorator is used to define method calling pattern whether methods allows only single object or multiple objects to invoke this method.

**@api.one**

This decorator loops automatically on Records of RecordSet for you. Self is redefined as current record

**Note:**
Caution: the returned value is put in a list. This is not always supported by the web client, e.g. on button action
methods. In that case, you should use **@api.multi** to decorate your method, and probably call **self.ensure_one()** in
the method definition.

**@api.multi**

Self will be the current RecordSet without iteration. It is the default behavior (multiple browsable objects). Methods which returns non premitive type data(list, dictionary, function) must be decorated with **@api.multi**

**@api.model**

This decorator will convert old API calls to decorated function to new API signature. It allows to be polite when
migrating code. Self does not contain any record/recordset in methods which are decorated by this decorator.

So simply call like this

**self.env['model_name'].method_name(arguments)**

Try with following code:

```
@api.depends('company_id')
def _get_country_code(self):
    """
    Return the country code of the user company. If not exists, return XX.
    """
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    for partner in self:
        user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(self.company_id)
        #NOTE: replace code name with your real field name where you want to see value 
        partner.code = user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id \
            and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'
```

Change *default_get()* method api from *@api.multi* to *@api.model*

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070640/valueerror-expected-singleton-odoo8?rq=1)

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

```
Please try this

    @api.multi
    def _get_country_code(self):
       code =False
       for partner in self:

          user_company = self.user_id
   #it will return the current login-ed user id 

          code = user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'
       return code
```