# Expected singleton Error "for" loop - Odoo server actions

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am using odoo web UI.

I am creating a new button in sale.order form to create RFQ.

The server action to create the RFQ is working well but not for the one2many order_line field.

I am getting the Expected singleton error

```
raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % record)
    ValueError: <class 'ValueError'>: "Expected singleton: sale.order.line(706, 707)" while evaluating
```

Here is the code I use to loop through the records:

```
for rec in record:
  if record.order_line:
    for line in record.order_line:
      if line.id:
        action = {
        "type": "ir.actions.server",
        "id": 601,
        "context": {"active_id": record.order_line.id, "active_model": "sale.order.line"}
        }
```

The "id":601 action is defined through the UI too: 
[image: action ID 601]

I tried to use this answer: 
[ValueError: Expected singleton: - Odoo v8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721153/valueerror-expected-singleton-odoo-v8)

But still have the singleton error.

What am I missing in the code for the action to loop through the lines of the `one2many` field `order_line` without the singleton error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO issue is in this line `"active_id": record.order_line.id`

`record.order_line` will have a list of records set. You do loop on it which is correct. `line` will represent a single record set. So you have to use `line`.

Try with following code:

```
for rec in record:
    for line in rec.order_line:
        action = {
            "type": "ir.actions.server",
            "id": 601,
            "context": {"active_id": line.id, 
                        "active_model": "sale.order.line"}
        }
```

Comment: thank you Bhavesh it is indeed working!
Now I have an issue with sale order id.. I don't understand why couldn't it be used several times? 

Odoo Server Error - Validation Error
×
The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.

Model: Purchase Order Line (purchase.order.line), Constraint: purchase_order_line_order_id_fkey

Comment: I don't have all code and not sure about your design/workflow, It is hard to understand. But start a new thread of your problem, provide your attempt code in question and current output & desire output.